# how to change <Text> value dynamically React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native. I want to change the text data in Render according to the data I have taken in MYSQL. When ItemDURUM = 0, it says Order Pending, and when itemDURUM = 1, it says Order Confirmed. At the moment 0 and 1 value is waiting for the text value of the order is waiting. What is the problem? Now I'm pulling variable 0 and 1 from MYSQL without problems

```
export default class usrFirst extends React.Component {

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  Text } from 'react-native';
import { Cell, Section, TableView } from 'react-native-tableview-simple';


    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
         itemDURUM:[]
    }
      responseMUSTERISIPARISDURUM() {
    fetch('http://....php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({

        BOYLAM: this.state...,
        ENLEM: this.state....

      })

    }).then((response) => response.text())
          .then((responseJson) => {

           if(responseJson.length > 0)
            {
                 this.setState({itemDURUM : responseJson});

        }
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
     }
    render() {
    return (
    <Cell cellStyle="RightDetail" title=<Text style={{color:'#00a7c0',fontWeight: "bold"}}>Durum</Text> detail= { this.state.itemDURUM === '0'? <Text style={{color:'#0094ff',fontWeight: "bold"}}>Order Pending</Text>: <Text style={{color:'#ff1706',fontWeight: "bold"}}>Order Confirmed</Text>} />
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the topic.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, is it something from the `itemDURUM` array?

Answer (score -1):

Your render method has some issues. I'm not sure where you call responseMUSTERISIPARISDURUM but try to change your render method to

```
render() {
    return (
        <Cell 
            cellStyle="RightDetail" 
            title={<Text style={{ color: '#00a7c0', fontWeight: "bold" }}>Durum</Text>} 
            detail={ 
                this.state.itemDURUM === '0' 
                ? <Text style={{ color: '#0094ff', fontWeight: "bold" }}>Order Pending</Text> 
                : <Text style={{ color: '#ff1706', fontWeight: "bold" }}>Order Confirmed</Text> 
            } 
        />
    )
}
```